# Comparar Un Registro Con Otro Registro de Otra Tabla PHP

Tags: php, html

Que tal comunidad, podrian ayudarme con este problema que tengo, no tengo mucho conocimiento, mi problema es que necesito comparar un registro de una tabla llamada "Empresas" en el cual guarda tanto langitud y latitud y necesito compararla en un registro que se hace al hacer un chequeo el cual se guarda en una tabla llamada "Chequeo" en cual guardo de igual manera longitud y latitud, lo que necesito es que compare si los registros coinciden, si no lo hace que no lo deje checar Espero y Ayuden

```html
<?php

include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');  
$hora = date('g:i:s');
$latitud = $_POST["latitud"];
$longitud = $_POST["longitud"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO chequeo
(nombre,fecha,hora,latitud,longitud)
VALUES ('$nombre','$fecha','$hora','$latitud','$longitud')";



$verificar_fecha = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM chequeo WHERE fecha = '$fecha' AND nombre='$nombre'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar_fecha) > 0 ){
 echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
                title:"Ya Has Checado Esto.!",
                text: "Sigue Trabajando Usuario",
                type:"error"
          },function(isConfirm){
             window.location.href = "../Usuario.php";  
          });
          $(".swal2-confirm").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "../Usuario.php";
          });});</script>';
 exit;
}
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
                title:"Chequeo Con Exito.!",
                text: "Bienvenido al Trabajo.!",
                type:"success"
          },function(isConfirm){
             window.location.href = "../Usuario.php";  
          });
          $(".swal2-confirm").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "../Usuario.php";
          });});</script>';
}else{
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
                title:"Upss.!",
                text: "Ocurrio un error, comunicate con tu Administrador",
                type:"error"
          },function(isConfirm){
             window.location.href = "../Usuario.php";  
          });
          $(".swal2-confirm").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "../Usuario.php";
          });});</script>';
}
?>
```

[image: Esta es la tabla de empresa]

[image: Y Esta es la de chequeo]

Comment: Podrías compartir las tablas que estan relacionadas a tu pregunta

Comment: Claro, Espera Ahorita, Comparto Las Imagenes

Comment: es preferible adjuntar la estructura de las tablas como texto

Comment: "Base De Datos Empresa"

SELECT `idempresa`, `nombrempresa`, `pais`, `cp`, `direccion`, `latitud`, `longitud`, `rfc`, `activo` FROM `reloj`.`empresa`

"Base De Datos Chequeo"

SELECT `id_Chequeo`, `nombre`, `fecha`, `hora`, `horaComida`, `regresoComida`, `horaS`, `latitud`, `longitud` FROM `reloj`.`chequeo